# Glass Mapper MVC: The name 'RenderLink' does not exist in the current context

Tags: razor, sitecore, glass-mapper, sitecore8, sitecore-mvc

I'm trying to get a Sitecore 8 project going with MVC and I am getting the following error:

> Compiler Error Message: CS0103: The name 'RenderLink' does not exist in the current context

I have as references (from the nuget packages)

- Castle.Core
- Glass.Mapper
- Glass.Mapper.Sc
- Glass.Mapper.Sc.Mvc

I've tried a few things with the views/web.config. Perhaps there are clashes?

```html
<namespaces>
        <add namespace="Sitecore.Mvc" />
        <add namespace="Sitecore.Data.Items" />
        <add namespace="System.Web.Mvc" />
        <add namespace="System.Web.Mvc.Ajax" />
        <add namespace="System.Web.Mvc.Html" />
        <add namespace="System.Web.Optimization"/>
        <add namespace="System.Web.Routing" />
        <add namespace="TDSExample.Web" />
        <add namespace="TDSExample.Entities.Ids" />
        <add namespace="Glass.Mapper.Sc" />
      </namespaces>
```

I've cleared the Sitecore cache. I'm not sure what I've missed.
Here is a cut down version of the view/rendering:

```html
@model Glass.Mapper.Sc.Web.Mvc.GlassView
<TDSExample.Entities.Templates.Header.Header>

  @using Glass.Mapper.Sc @{ Layout = null; var dataSource = Sitecore.Context.Database.GetItem(Sitecore.Mvc.Presentation.RenderingContext.Current.Rendering.DataSource) ?? Sitecore.Context.Item; }

  <h1>@Model.Editable(x => x.Title, dataSource)</h1>
  <p>
    @Model.Editable(x => x.Subtitle, dataSource)
  </p>
  @RenderLink(x => x.ReadMoreLink, dataSource, new { @class = "read-more" })
```

Here is a cut down version of the rendering:

```html
@model Glass.Mapper.Sc.Web.Mvc.GlassView
    <TDSExample.Entities.Templates.Header.Header>

      @using Glass.Mapper.Sc @{ Layout = null; var dataSource = Sitecore.Context.Database.GetItem(Sitecore.Mvc.Presentation.RenderingContext.Current.Rendering.DataSource) ?? Sitecore.Context.Item; }

      <h1>@Model.Editable(x => x.Title, dataSource)</h1>
      <p>
        @Model.Editable(x => x.Subtitle, dataSource)
      </p>
      @RenderLink(x => x.ReadMoreLink, dataSource, new { @class = "read-more" })
```

The test fields rendering just fine. I must be missing a reference somewhere. Putting "@using Glass.Mapper.Sc" or "@using Glass.Mapper.Sc/Mvc" stops VS highlighting it as an error.
I just can't see what I've missed. Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

change this

```
@model Glass.Mapper.Sc.Web.Mvc.GlassView<TDSExample.Entities.Templates.Header.Header>
```

into this

```
@inherits Glass.Mapper.Sc.Web.Mvc.GlassView<TDSExample.Entities.Templates.Header.Header>
```

And access the methods on the view instead of the model:

```
@Editable(m => m.Title)
@RenderLink(m => m.ReadMoreLink)

<!--this should work as well for links--> 
@Editable(m => m.ReadMoreLink)
```

Added bonus: you should not have to set the layout to null. Make sure you do not have a _ViewStart.cshtml which could cause this.

Comment: That's the ticket! Thank you very much. It was even there in [Tutorial 12](http://www.glass.lu/Mapper/Sc/Tutorials/Tutorial12) looking back but I hadn't realised!
Thank you for your time.